# Access an array inside an array in Twig

Tags: arrays, twig

I have an array of the following form with many items. How can I get the values of the "data" key in Twig?

```
array(4) {
["schema"]=>
  string(20) "decision_public.json"
  ["data"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    array(8) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(23) "looks_bad_account_abuse"
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "Looks Bad"
}
```

I tried `for` inside a `for`, but I cant get the data.

Comment: `{% for row in var['data'] %}{{ row.name }}{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 2):

@DarkBee you gave me an idea here is the solution:

```
{% for key, decision in decisions %}
        {% if key=='data' %}
        {% for item in decisions['data'] %}
         <option>{{item.id}}</option>
         {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```